# Division returns something different in functions

Tags: swift

Paste the following code into a playground:

```
5.0 / 100

func test(anything: Float) -> Float {
    return anything / 100
}

test(5.0)
```

The first line should return 0.05 as expected.  The function test returns 0.0500000007450581.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with functions.  Your first example is using type `Double` which represents floating point numbers more precisely by using 64 bits.  If you were to change your second example to:

```
func test(anything: Double) -> Double {
    return anything / 100
}

test(5.0)
```

You would get the result you expect.  `Float` uses only 32 bits of data, thus it provides a less precise representation of the number.  Also, floating point numbers are stored as binary values and frequently are only an approximation of the base 10 representation.  That is why `0.05` is showing up as `0.0500000007450581` when stored as a `Float`.